# Contributions of variables in Log-Log models

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, log-linear

I have built a model on `log(units)` sold and want to measure the contribution of each independent variable in the model (which are also in `log`) i.e. proportions of predicted units explained by independent variables.

So, basically I have a log-log model and want these contributions to be in actual units.

Under usual circumstances, I would be using an additive model but since now I am using a log-log transformation (multiplicative model) I think the process of calculating contribution will be different than additive. 
How should I go about it?